# SharedPref Check After Click

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a system that, when a user downloads my app, the user earns coins. Users must press the verify button after installation. Yes, he can earn a coin. But I am trying to do a disable verify button after one click because after app installs users can press a lot of times and earn a lot of coins. (verify button: check app installation and give a coin to the user)
When user clicks verify button sharedprefs value go False

But I don't understand that it is not working. I tried to implement code in different positions and try to insert new boolean for holding "canearn" data but it doesn't work.
Thanks for your help.
(Sorry for bad syntax :( )

```
  private SharedPreferences coins;
  private SharedPreferences sharedPref ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    coins = getSharedPreferences("Rewards", MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("canearn",MODE_PRIVATE);

    bttn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.veribut1);
     bttn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         //   SharedPreferences getter = getSharedPreferences("canearn", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
         //   boolean test = sharedPref.getBoolean("canearn",true);

        if(sharedPref.getBoolean("canearn",true) == true) {

                final List<String> installedPackages = getInstalledAppsPackageNameList();
                String packageNameC = "com.********";


                    if (installedPackages.contains(packageNameC)) {

                    int coinCount = Integer.parseInt(coins.getString("Coins", "0"));

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("canearn", false); //add boolean
                    editor.commit(); //save
                    coinCount = coinCount + 500;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor coinsEdit = coins.edit();
                    coinsEdit.putString("Coins", String.valueOf(coinCount));
                    coinsEdit.apply();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Coin Earned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                }    else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Install and Open App first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
            else
            {             
       Log.i("app","dontcount");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: as per the below-mentioned answer, you can disable the button when you verify. If you go back and coming to same screen while rendering you must check if(sharedPref.getBoolean("canearn",true) == true) condition whether you want to enable button or not. It does not work inside  the onclick checking the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Well,there are many ways to achieve your goal but if you want to disable the button.
You can just use

```
bttn3.setEnabled(false);
```

at the end of your `onClick()` function.
No need to make preferences false
You should also setVisibility() as per your question to make the button invisible as you won't be needing it.

Comment: do not answer if you do not understand. In comments section, you can mention your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, inside the onCreate() method, check the SharedPreferences value for the coin. If the user has received a coin,

```
bttn3.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: upvote will be given if your answer is useful. Do not need to mention explicitly.